# Kile on windows 7 - Missing settings option

Tags: windows, kile

I added another button to the toolbar. Before adding that, there was a "configure kile" or something similar in the settings tab. After adding the button that option is not visible. So now I have no way to go to Kile settings. Even removing the button from the toolbar does not resolve this. Any ideas?
Windows 7
Kile ver 3.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. It seems to be a bug but a workaround is to edit the toolbars (by right clicking on the empty space next to a toolbar) and clicking "edit toolbars". Then you add "Configure Kile" to a toolbar, click Ok and you have the option to configure Kile sitting on your toolbar.